# Uri.OriginalString is encoded in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

recently I upgraded to windows 8.1 respectively to IIS 8.5.

I am having a WCF web service which get the original url with:

```
var url = operationContext.IncomingMessageProperties.Via;
```

Lets say that the url is: `http://localhost/?email=test@test.com` (this is the original url)

Before upgrade in `url.OriginalString` I was receiving the exact original url.
After upgrade in `url.OriginalString` I am receiving `http://localhost/?email=test%40test.com`

Any idea what could be the reason for that?

Thanks.

Comment: The url is just the same, but encoded.

Comment: Absolutely, the question is that before the upgrade to 8.5 the url.OriginalString was containing NOT encoded string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseLegacyRequestUrlGeneration" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

This solved my problem.

The source of the solution is: http://programmaticallyspeaking.com/the-mysteriously-escaped-request-path-in-aspnet.html

THANKS!

Comment: I don't know what this is and that article is way over my head but thanks! I ended up fixing this by using "AbsoluteUri" instead of "OriginalString", but this was good to discover, thanks again for posting the source.